# How to update the state of a useState component outside of the useEffect that transforms the State variable?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I manage to read a selection variable declared as const[selection, setSelection] = useState([]) and I need to update it in setSelection to send it to another file with useContext.

But, my other file well provider, does not receive any selection even in a useEffect()

I would conserve useContext and not use Redux or RTK

In my configuration, it is not advisable to reverse the parent/children.

```js
import '../styles/Filters.css'
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { SelectionContext } from '../App'
import Budget from '../components/Budget'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Filters() {
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState({})
    const [minValue2, setMinValue2] = useState(0)
    const [maxValue2, setMaxValue2] = useState(0)

    let [selection, setSelection] = useContext(SelectionContext)

    useEffect(
        (send) => {
            if (
                Object.keys(filters)[0] !== undefined &&
                Object.keys(Object.values(filters)[0])[0] === '0'
            ) {
                if (!selection.some((el) => Object.keys(filters)[0] in el)) {
                    selection.push({
                        [Object.keys(filters)[0]]: [Object.values(filters)[0]],
                    })
                } else if (
                    selection.some((el) => Object.keys(filters)[0] in el) &&
                    !selection.some((el) =>
                        Object.values(el)[0].includes(Object.values(filters)[0])
                    )
                ) {
                    let indexOfTitle = 0
                    indexOfTitle = selection.findIndex(
                        (obj) => Object.keys(filters)[0] === Object.keys(obj)[0]
                    )
                    selection[indexOfTitle][Object.keys(filters)[0]].push(
                        Object.values(filters)[0]
                    )
                } else if (
                    selection.some((el) => Object.keys(filters)[0] in el) &&
                    selection.some((el) =>
                        Object.values(el)[0].includes(Object.values(filters)[0])
                    )
                ) {
                    let indexOfTitle = 0
                    indexOfTitle = selection.findIndex(
                        (obj) => Object.keys(filters)[0] === Object.keys(obj)[0]
                    )
                    let indexOfId = selection[indexOfTitle][
                        Object.keys(filters)[0]
                    ].indexOf(Object.values(filters)[0])
                    selection[indexOfTitle][Object.keys(filters)[0]].splice(
                        indexOfId,
                        1
                    )
                    if (
                        selection[indexOfTitle][Object.keys(filters)[0]]
                            .length === 0
                    ) {
                        selection.splice(indexOfTitle, 1)
                    }
                }
            }     
        },
        [filters, selection]
    )

    console.log(selection)

    useEffect(() => {
        setSelection(selection)
    }, [selection, setSelection])

    return (
        <>
            <Budget
                setMinValue2={setMinValue2}
                setMaxValue2={setMaxValue2}
                setFilters={setFilters}
            />
        </>
    )

}
```

Comment: The word send isn't in the code !

Answer (score 0):

Have you passed `[selection, setSelection]` to your `SelectionContext.Provider` ?

make sure you have passed them like this :

```
<SelectionContext.Provider value={[selection, setSelection]}>
    <Filters />
</SelectionContext>
```